How do I receive notifications about invitations to Google Chat spaces?
I know I can see invitations to spaces by clicking on New Chat, then Browse Spaces, as shown:

However, I haven't seen another notification that I've been invited to a space. Is there a way to see invitations without having to browse the list of spaces every time?
I'm using Google Workspace, in case that has some connection.
